# Navbar overlapping last ListView item (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdk-tools

[image]

My problem is similar to above Image

I am getting this issue in Nexus Devices. I added margin from bottom by getting **Bottom Navigation Bar** height. But my application is showing extra margin from the bottom on a tablet.

I do not want to change anything in my style file.

```
Code:- 
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/clubhouse_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/clubhouse_toolbar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                             android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium.Inverse"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ab_arrowup"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drop_down_overlay_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The drop_down_overlay_container in this framelayout is where I am showing my Fragment.

Comment: Can you complete the question by posting additional details, such as the layout you are using, or any relevant code?

Comment: Sry for less information.

Comment: Can you provide us with a screenshot and mark the exact spot of the problem

Comment: Yes sure please check my problem is similar to above image

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it :) What is the test device tablet?

Comment: try removing `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 39):

Ok the problem is the following, the cardview match parent height is actually the full screen height with top bar. An very easy fix for this is to add:

```
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.jburg.empty.Main22Activity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main22"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

This works on my emulator nexus 10 tablet. Let me know if this helps you otherwise I'll keep searching :)

Comment: even i checked by removing the margin. I just want to know the root cause

Comment: Really Thanks, I checked on Sony Xperia Model number:- SGP771 and Version :- 5.02

Comment: But i do not resolve my problem.Because my problem is related to other devices margin from bottom is not the perfect solution. If you want +50 point not an issue but i am curious for root cause

Comment: Still not? Still same result?

Comment: Yes, Even i am surprise way this thing happens.

Comment: Thanks my friend for you cooperation Really appriciable  :) Its working now. and its for all please add  android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"  its works for me

Comment: Can you please tell the exact region why we need to add this.

Comment: I think you mean reason and yes I can: The top bar has a certain height, the fragment tries to be the full height of the screen without looking at the top bar so the bottom of this fragment will be outside the screen.

Comment: This is not any solution. There is extra bottom margin on devices without soft navbar.

Comment: @user1209216, I think you are right. You could try adding this to styles <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item> , like the solution in the link Smartiz supplied http://stackoverflow.com/q/27723322/1607191.

Comment: No, I could not try to add this to styles. I want color status bar. WTF, where is the real reason? Google fault or what?

Comment: This gives too much margin at the bottom, it doesn't fit the bottom soft navbar.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to the CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score 1):

did you try this

[Bottom soft NavigationBar overlaps my ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27723322/1607191)

The Only problem is that you mention you don't want to change your style file ( didn't mention why! ) and that user achieve your result by changing style file.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this code in imageview.

`android:layout_below="@+id/clubhouse_toolbar_main"`

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion :
You could add a dummy button with visibility="invisible"(not "gone"). The default height of a button is almost same as that of the Navigation Bar. So even if the Navigation bar is over the button, your important data will be fully visible(Above the navigation bar). And you don't have to think about the button being seen.

In your case i'm assuming that you have some scrollable view in your Fragment. So you should put the button inside your fragment xml under your scrolllable view(listview, recyclerview ...) or at the bottom of your fragment xml.

Comment: The problem with this is that you don't know how many dp the navbar takes on every device.

Comment: you don't have to worry about the dp. In every screen size the default height of a button is almost same as that of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

just add bottom padding same as height of bottom navigation bar in RecyclerView.

Comment: The problem with this is that you don't know how many dp the navbar takes on every device.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar problem. I tried with all possible solution But din't work. Then I tried by myself by adding the View element to my parent as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".FilterLocationActivity">

  <include layout="@layout/app_bar" />

  <ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvLocations"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tester"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

  <View
    android:id="@+id/tester"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I would like to share this with you. Inside the activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    window.goEdgeToEdge()
    binding = ActivityStoreBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    findNavController().setGraph(R.navigation.store_nav_graph, getStoreBundle())
}

/**
 * Set various flags to go edge to edge
 */
private fun Window.goEdgeToEdge() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. I was using theme NoActionBar and ConstraintsLayout as parent layout. None of the answer here worked in my case. Finally the following solution worked for me. Hopefully it help someone.

Just add these line to your RecyclerView/ListView

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

Here is my complete recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvProducts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like something related to [SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION). Make sure that your activity does not have this flag set in `setSystemUiVisibility`

Comment: Sry i didn't added this flag

Comment: Do you have any other idea. I added by getting navbar height but i am getting extra margin from bottom in certain devices