# Android Samsung Galaxy s10 soft key buttons bar is hiding our application bottom view

Tags: android, themes, samsung-galaxy, android-softbuttons

I am using my own navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. Its working properly in all devices but in Samsung Galaxy s10, this bottom navigation bar is getting hidden. I guess this is because of soft key buttons bar. From here [Bottom soft NavigationBar overlaps my ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723322/bottom-soft-navigationbar-overlaps-my-listview) 
I have tried using `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>` this in my theme and it fix the issue but if I use this parameter in my theme then status bar color that is **colorPrimaryDark** is not working.

My Layout file is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_area"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@color/C12">

            <include layout="@layout/parts_search_header" />

            <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
                android:id="@+id/top_view_pager_tab_strip"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/C17"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/C10"
                app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
                app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="15dp"
                app:pstsTextColorSelected="@color/C11"
                app:pstsUnderlineColor="@color/border1"
                app:pstsUnderlineHeight="1dp"
                app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
                app:pstsTabBackground="@drawable/touchstates_tab_strip"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/top_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

        </FrameLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/layout_footer_ad_view" />

    <!-- bottom_navigation -->
    <include layout="@layout/layout_bottom_navigation"/>
    <!-- /bottom_navigation -->
</LinearLayout>
```

I have attached images for your reference. How to fix this issue.

[image: Bottom bar is hidden in Samsung galaxy s10]

[image]

Comment: show your layout XML

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have updated with layout xml file